# Android viewPager and Fragment interface loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a viewpager and 3 fragments(representing 3 pages).
2 of the pages are have identical fields. 
When I swipe between pages/fragments, the onscreen variables seem to get confused between fragment1 and fragment2.

I was wondering, are the fragment variables cached, and somehow Java/Android thinks the variables on each page are the same thing.

Or, do I need to reload the onscreen variables each time the fragment/page is displayed. If so, where do I do this, in fragment.onCreate, fragment.onCreateView, or from the activity/viewpager itself after the fragment is loaded/displayed.

Any help/knowledge is greatly appreciated.

cheers.

Comment: For sure the fragment variables may still reside in memory. It depends on the code, specifically related to context and scope of the objects/variables. Pls post code if you want any help from anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this, reading documentation is the only one way to get full information. [Fragment-Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) .
And fragments are classes, suppose you have three fragment tabs, you will have FragmentA and its layout fragmentA.xml , FragmentB.java and fragmentb.xml, and so on.

every fragment must have following

```
public static class FragmentA extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false);
   }
}
```

Class and its layout inflate, it tells what things will be displayed on fragment, and each of it has its own functions. so for example, FragmentA will show you contacts, FragmentB will groups so both of them have its own function. so you can have separate variables for their purpose.

Hope it helps!

after all, read documentation. There is all information, how you can create fragment and attach it in your mainActivity.